# heroku run rails db asking for password that i never set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

After deploying rails project on Heroku,I tried to get into the database console but when i run:

`$ heroku run rails db`

it is asking for password:

```
Password:
```

I forget the password,now i want to create table in database, any solution to setup password again??

Comment: Can´t you do it on Heroku page?

Comment: Did you try https://id.heroku.com/account/password/reset ?

Answer (score 0):

`heroku pg:psql` is the canonical (and faster!) way to connect to heroku db.

The reason `heroku run rails db` doesn't work is because what it does is it creates a one-off process on Heroku with your codebase and runs `rails db` command there. `rails db` depends on `$RAILS_ENV` environment variable to fetch db credentials from `config/database.yml` which doesn't work on Heroku.

If you must know your Heroku db password you can get it from `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`